# Comments form custom fields order

Tags: custom-field, comments, order, comment-form

I'm trying to add 5 custom fields to comment form. Just use 2 hooks to display custom fields after default fields - 'comment_form_logged_in_after' and 'comment_form_after_fields' like this:

```
function kvkoolitus_registration_additional_fields () {

  echo '<p class="comment-form-code">'.
  '<label for="code">' . __( 'Personal code', 'kvkoolitus' ) . ' <span class="required">*</span> </label>'.
  '<input id="code" name="code" type="text" size="30"  tabindex="5" /></p>';

  echo '<p class="comment-form-phone">'.
  '<label for="phone">' . __( 'Phone','kvkoolitus' ) . ' <span class="required">*</span> </label>'. 
  '<input id="phone" name="phone" type="text" size="30"  tabindex="5" /></p>';

  echo '<p class="comment-form-address">'.
  '<label for="address">' . __( 'Address','kvkoolitus' ) . '</label>'.
  '<input id="address" name="address" type="text" size="30"  tabindex="5" /></p>';

  echo '<p class="comment-form-company">'.
  '<label for="company">' . __( 'Company','kvkoolitus' ) . '</label>'.
  '<input id="company" name="company" type="text" size="30"  tabindex="5" /></p>';

  echo '<p class="comment-form-profession">'.
  '<label for="profession">' . __( 'Profession','kvkoolitus' ) . '</label>'.
  '<input id="profession" name="profession" type="text" size="30"  tabindex="5" /></p>'; 
}

add_action( 'comment_form_logged_in_after', 'kvkoolitus_registration_additional_fields' );
add_action( 'comment_form_after_fields', 'kvkoolitus_registration_additional_fields' );
```

When someone is logged in, first come required fields (name, email), additional fields and then comment field, just like I need. But if user is not logged in, comment field display at first position. Why is this happen and how to solve this?
[image: wrong order]

Comment: The plugin is at fault here, or perhaps there is another earlier hook you should be using.  For example, is there a `comment_form_before_fields` hook, which would get your custom fields rendered before the comment textarea field?  You need to look at the plugin source code or documentation, to see about this.

Comment: When I use a hook 'comment_form_before_fields' and 'comment_form_logged_in_before' hooks, it puts required fields (name, email) at the bottom of the form. Comment field is still first in order.

Comment: contact the plugin developer...it's their problem...

Comment: Actually I try to do this by myself, so I need to know how to add custom fields to comment form and display them in the right order)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Demo - Setup

Here's a demo how we could control the display of comment fields and their order:

Let's create a custom class:

```
$mycf = new MyCommentFields;
```

Then we define our extra fields:

```
$myfields = [];

$myfields['myaddress'] = sprintf(
    '<p class="comment-form-myaddress">
         <label for="myaddress">%s <span class="required">*</span></label>
         <input id="myaddress" name="myaddress" type="text" size="30" tabindex="5" />
     </p>', 
    esc_html__( 'Address', 'kvkoolitus' )
); 

$myfields['myphone'] = sprintf(
    '<p class="comment-form-myphone">
         <label for="myphone">%s <span class="required">*</span></label>
         <input id="myphone" name="myphone" type="text" size="30" tabindex="5" />
     </p>', 
    esc_html__( 'Phone', 'kvkoolitus' )
);
```

and set it with:

```
$mycf->set_extra_fields_logged_in(  $myfields );
$mycf->set_extra_fields_logged_out( $myfields );
```

Next we set the display-order for those fields:

```
$mycf->set_fields_order_logged_in( 
    [ 
        'myaddress', 
        'myphone', 
        'comment', 
    ] 
);
```

and:

```
$mycf->set_fields_order_logged_out( 
    [ 
        'author', 
        'email', 
        'url', 
        'myaddress', 
        'myphone', 
        'comment' 
    ] 
);
```

Then we initialize it:

```
$mycf->init();
```

We could then hook this into the `comment_form_before` action.

### Demo - Class

Here's our demo class (*PHP 5.4+*):

```
class MyCommentFields
{
    private $extra_fields_logged_in;
    private $extra_fields_logged_out;
    private $fields_order_logged_in;
    private $fields_order_logged_out;

    public function init()
    {
        // logged-out case
        add_filter( 'comment_form_fields',          [ $this, 'comment_form_fields' ] );

        // logged-in case
        add_filter( 'comment_form_field_comment',   [ $this, 'comment_form_field_comment' ] );      
    }

    public function set_extra_fields_logged_in( array $extra_fields_logged_in )
    {
        $this->extra_fields_logged_in = $extra_fields_logged_in;
    }

    public function set_extra_fields_logged_out( array $extra_fields_logged_out )
    {
        $this->extra_fields_logged_out = $extra_fields_logged_out;
    }

    public function set_fields_order_logged_in( array $fields_order_logged_in )
    {
        $this->fields_order_logged_in = $fields_order_logged_in;
    }

    public function set_fields_order_logged_out( array $fields_order_logged_out )
    {
        $this->fields_order_logged_out = $fields_order_logged_out;
    }

    public function comment_form_field_comment( $field )
    {
        // logged-in case
        if( is_user_logged_in() && ! empty( $this->extra_fields_logged_in ) ) 
        {
            $tmp = '';
            foreach( $this->fields_order_logged_in as $key )
            {
                if( 'comment' === $key  )
                    $tmp .= $field;
                elseif( isset( $this->extra_fields_logged_in[$key] ) )
                    $tmp .= $this->extra_fields_logged_in[$key];
            }
            if( $tmp )
                $field = $tmp;
        }
        return $field;
    }

    public function comment_form_fields( $fields )
    {
        // logged-out case
        if( ! is_user_logged_in() && ! empty( $this->extra_fields_logged_out ) ) 
        {
            $tmp = [];
            foreach( $this->fields_order_logged_out as $key )
            {
                if( isset( $fields[$key] ) )
                    $tmp[$key] = $fields[$key];             
                elseif( isset( $this->extra_fields_logged_out[$key] ) )
                    $tmp[$key] = $this->extra_fields_logged_out[$key];
            }   
            if( ! empty( $tmp ) ) 
                $fields = $tmp;
        }       
        return $fields;
    }

} // end class
```

Hopefully you can adjust the demo to your needs.

### Previous answer:

Here's one hack, to prepend extra fields, that should work for both *logged-in* and *logged-out* case:

```
add_filter( 'comment_form_fields', function( $fields )
{
      echo '<p class="comment-form-code">'.
           '<label for="code">' . __( 'Personal code', 'kvkoolitus' ) . ' <span class="required">*</span> </label>'.
           '<input id="code" name="code" type="text" size="30"  tabindex="5" /></p>';

      echo '<p class="comment-form-phone">'.
           '<label for="phone">' . __( 'Phone','kvkoolitus' ) . ' <span class="required">*</span> </label>'. 
           '<input id="phone" name="phone" type="text" size="30"  tabindex="5" /></p>';

      echo '<p class="comment-form-address">'.
           '<label for="address">' . __( 'Address','kvkoolitus' ) . '</label>'.
           '<input id="address" name="address" type="text" size="30"  tabindex="5" /></p>';

      echo '<p class="comment-form-company">'.
           '<label for="company">' . __( 'Company','kvkoolitus' ) . '</label>'.
           '<input id="company" name="company" type="text" size="30"  tabindex="5" /></p>';

      echo '<p class="comment-form-profession">'.
           '<label for="profession">' . __( 'Profession','kvkoolitus' ) . '</label>'.
           '<input id="profession" name="profession" type="text" size="30"  tabindex="5" /></p>'; 

    return $fields;
} );
```

Note that the dynamic `comment_form_field_{$name}` filter for the *logged-out* case will not be available for those fields.

Otherwise one could inject the new fields into the `$comments_fields` within the `comment_form_fields` filter and make sure they come before the default fields.  This will only display for the *logged-out* case. Then for the *logged-out* case the `comment_form_logged_in_after` hook is available.

Comment: hmm..with your solution comment field outputed at the end of the form for both cases, logged in and logged out users, just like I wanted. But right now, default fields (name and email) outputs at the end of the form for users, which are not logged in.

Comment: did you check the order of fields in the HTML source, just in case it's CSS changing the order ? @anton

Comment: HTML sourse is the same: code, phone, address, company, profession, comment and just then goes author and email

Comment: yes that was the order I was aiming for, injecting your custom fields above the default fields ;-) so you don't want that order or ... ? PS: Your description *"When someone is logged in, first come required fields (name, email),"* doesn't match the screenshot and are not usually required for logged in users @anton

Comment: I need to display fields in this order: name, email, code, phone, address, company, profession, comment. If someone is logged in, default name and email field should be hidden, because we already know this information. Like on screenshot.

Comment: I updated the answer - Please update the question with this order info @anton

Comment: Right now the order in both cases absolutelly right. But for users who are not logged in, custom fields displayed twice. Name, email, code, phone, address, company, profession and then goes code, phone, address, company profession once again before comment field.

Comment: I updated the answer to hopefully fix that ;-) @anton

Comment: Thank you birgire for your support! The fields order is right now.))

Comment: ok great, you're welcome @anton

Comment: Hi birgire! Do you know how to add these custom fields to a comment metabox on post edit screen?

Comment: Hi @anton, it would be better served as a new question ,-)

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/232401/add-comments-meta-fields-to-comments-metabox-on-post-edit-screen

Comment: I have a problem with these fields translation. I added 'esc_html__' as a key to my .po files. I see these words in .po files, already translated to estonian and russian, but on front page I see default english words. Translations only available for default fields - Name, email and comment field

Comment: Not sure what's happening with your translations, better ask a new question for that ;-) @anton

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/233022/custom-values-are-not-translated

Comment: very strange situation @birgire , do you know how to fix it?

Comment: yes, but I haven't used qtranslate so I'm not sure if that's a factor @anton