# Add comments meta fields to comments metabox on post edit screen

Tags: custom-post-types, comments, metabox, comment-form, customization

I have few custom fields in comment form. How can I add these fields to comments metabox? I divide my question on 3 parts:

**1) How to remove url field and add custom comment fields to comment quick edit form?** 
 
[image: comments metabox]

**2) How to add custom fields to comment add form?** 
[image: comment add form]

**3) Hot to add custom meta information to comment metabox here?** 
[image: comment list metabox]

Comment: Can you post code of what you tried to achieve this? And I suppose you may need to ask it as three different questions, it's not as simple as that.These additions need to be done via JavaScript as the comments are fetched via AJAX response using `WP_Post_Comments_List_Table` and fields are copied from predefined form table via `wp_comment_reply()`.

Comment: I tried to find a hook to modify this metabox, but without success. I posted this questions in one place, because it's a one metabox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the hooks:

```
manage_{$this->screen->id}_columns
manage_{$this->screen->id}_sortable_columns
manage_comments_custom_column
```

are not available for the *post-comments* list table, constructed within the  `wp_ajax_get-comments` call. That table consists only of two columns: author and comment. The data for author, avatar, email, url and IP is displayed in the first column.

We can on the other hand use a hack like:

```
add_filter( 'get_comment_author_IP', function( $comment_author_IP, $comment_ID, $comment )
{
    if( doing_action( 'wp_ajax_get-comments' ) )
        echo 'Some Custom Text <br/>';

    return $comment_author_IP;
}, 10, 3 );
```

to display some data, in the first column, for each row. We could e.g. use a `get_user_meta()` call here.

Regarding how we can add custom input fields to the *quick-edit* comment form, we can also use a hack like this one:

```
add_filter( 'the_editor', function( $html )
{   
    if( did_action( 'load-post.php' ) && false !== strpos( $html, 'id="replycontent"' ) )
        $html .= sprintf( 
            '<br/> %s <input type="text" name="newcomment_myphone" value="%s">',
            esc_html__( 'Phone', 'wpse' )
        );

    return $html;
} );
```

where we target the `replycontent` editor it on the `post.php` screen. This might need further restriction. The field displays below the comment content editor:

[image: custom field]

It should then be possible to hook into the `edit_comment` action to store it into the user meta.

This should also work for the *Add comment* form but you might need javascript to insert the current value to the custom field. I'm sure it's also possible to inject the custom fields, to the comment form, with javascript instead of the approach listed above.

You could try to hide the URL field with CSS:

```
#author-url, label[for="author-url"] {
    display:none;
}
```

Hopefully you can adjust this further.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. With your help I solved my problem. Thanks!)

Comment: no problem, glad to hear it helped @anton

Comment: By the way, how we can check if comment updated? When wordpress loads comments, **doing_action( 'wp_ajax_get-comments' )** check works well, but there should be another check something like **when comment updated** to refresh values.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean (javascript or php check), but maybe it would be better served as a new question instead? - also because it's been a while since I looked at this problem so others might be more fresh on the topic than I am now ;-) @anton

Comment: take a look @birgire , maybe you know the answer - https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/264764/display-comment-meta-data-after-quick-update

Comment: The code to add a field to the quick-edit dropdown on the admin-comments screen does not work when you hit the 'reply' link for  a a comment. The 'phone' field that you added does not show up. This is with WP 5.8.3 and PHP 5.4.27.

Comment: thanks for that info @RickHellewell